# Are these Laplace transforms wrong in Stroud's Advanced Engineering Math Book?

Tags: laplace-transform, solution-verification

I know that if you think a book is wrong, most probably it is your own mistake. However, I can't understand the following Laplace transforms in K. A. Stroud's "Advanced Engineering Mathematics". In page 131 (Harmonic Oscillators part), it is written:

$$
af''(t)+bf(t)=0 \quad f(0)=\alpha,\;f'(0)=\beta
$$

$$
L\{af''(t)+bf(t)\}=L\{0\}
$$

$$
a[s^2F(s)-s\alpha-\beta]+bF(s)=0
$$

$$
(as^2+b)F(s)=s\alpha+\beta
$$

$$
F(s)=\frac{s(\alpha/a)}{s^{2}+(b/a)}+\frac{\beta/a}{s^{2}+(b/a)}
$$

giving:

$$
f(t)=\frac{\alpha}{a}Cos\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}t+\frac{\beta}{a}Sin\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}t
$$

However, according to me it should be as below:

$$
(as^2+b)F(s)=as\alpha+a\beta
$$

$$
F(s)=\frac{s\alpha}{s^{2}+(b/a)}+\frac{\beta}{s^{2}+(b/a)}
$$

which should give:

$$
f(t)=\alpha Cos\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}t+\beta\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}Sin\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}t
$$

> Is there a mistake in the book or am I terribly missing something?

Comment: Agree the textbook answer does not satisfy the initial conditions. For future reference, I found some errata here, but not sure if they are for your edition (and they don't include your case). http://www.palgrave.com/stroud/stroud7e/other/errata.pdf

Comment: @JasonZimba My book is 4th edition and errata doesn't cover this. I don't know if it is corrected in later editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check would be to plug it back into the original differential equation and see if it works.

Also note that the book's result doesn't satisfy the initial conditions, since $f(0) = \alpha/a \neq \alpha$. Whereas your result does.

Taking your function: $$f(t) = \alpha \cos \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} t + \beta \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \sin \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} t$$

We wish to show that $af'' + bf = 0$.

$$a f''(t) = - \alpha b \cos \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} t - \beta b \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \sin  \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} t = - b f(t)$$

So then we see that $af'' + bf = 0$, which means you are correct.

Also it is useful to solve the DE is multiple ways as a check.  We can quickly see that two linearly independent solutions to $f'' = -b/a f$ is $\sin(\sqrt{b/a} t)$ and $\cos(\sqrt{b/a}t)$.  Which means the solution to the differential equation is of the form $A\cos(\sqrt{b/a}t) + B\sin(\sqrt{b/a}t = f(t)$ then solve for $A$ and $B$ given the initial conditions.

Comment: I didn't really think that the book is actually wrong so checking initial conditions never crossed my mind. Thank you for your confirmation.